# ubuntu Installation problem

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install ubuntu (64bit amd) alongside windows 7,
From Bootable sandisc usb flash , but when i am trying to choose 'try ubuntu' or 'install ubuntu' its stoped on black screen with hide and show horizontal cursor and do nothing.
I tried 13.10 , 14.04 but the same problem.
Please reply to me soon with the soluition.
Thanks in advance.

Ps: My laptop ram was 3GB but i increased it to 4GB.

My laptop:
Asus: model x61s , 4GB Ram , windows 7 64bit , processor intel(R).

Comment: Have you tried booting using `nomodest` ?

Comment: Yes its not work for me.

Comment: `apci=off`, what about this ?

Comment: I jsut tried it , the same problem.

Comment: i tried the boot on another laptop it works fine.

Comment: I test and try out all options: "acpi=off" , "nolapic" , "edd=on", "nomodeset" , " normaraid" and "free software only".

Comment: all options give the same problem except  "nolapic" its enter and then stopped with the logo and loader screen.

Comment: Please any help?

Comment: Try starting the installer directly.

Comment: Try using 32-bit (or 64-bit).

Comment: Remove `quiet splash` from the boot parameters and add `debug` so that you get more helpful output and then report back where it hangs. Regarding using `nomodeset` etc., your laptop has Radeon HD4570 GPU which should be supported in 14.04, so this flag should not be necessary.

Comment: I tried the debug using nomodeset  and it stopped on the following line: IMA: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p20j9bvlgdhbg1z/2014-05-25%2020.56.00.jpg

Answer (score 1):

My machine is an Asus x60s and the following helped:

Open your BIOS settings
Navigate to Security > I/O Interface security
Change New interface card to LOCKED and save the settings.
Voilá! You can boot without nolapic and you can see all your cores.